# Initial objects in the category of bilinear maps $M \times N \to L$. where $M,N$ are fixed $R$-modules, and $L$ arbitrary $R$-module.

Tags: category-theory, modules, tensor-products, bilinear-form, morphism

In our class we are looking at the definition of tensor product, and here’s a (paraphased) remark that I don’t get.

> Let $M,N$ be fixed $R$-modules, and $L$ an arbitrary $R$-module. At this point we only know that the tensor product $M \bigotimes_R N$ is a $R$-module, such that there exists a bilinear map $\Phi: M \times N \to M \bigotimes_R N$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$ be the category of bilinear maps $M \times N \to L$.
>
> Then $\text{Hom}_R(M \bigotimes_R N, L)$ (the set of $R$-linear maps M $\bigotimes_R N \to L$) being isomorphic to $\text{Hom}_R(M, N; L)$ (the set of bilinear maps $ M \times N \to L$) is equivalent to $\Phi$ being an initial object in $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$.

I interpret this as saying that, given an object $g$ in $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$, there exists only one morphism $\Phi \to g$. How does $\text{Hom}_R(M \bigotimes_R N, L) \simeq \text{Hom}_R(M,N; L)$ imply this?

Comment: My note says that $\text{Hom}_R(M \bigotimes_R N, L)$ is the set of $R$-linear maps M $\bigotimes_R N \to L$, while $\text{Hom}_R(M,N; L)$ is the set of bilinear maps $ M \times N \to L$. Given $\Phi$ as above, and $f \in \text{Hom}_R(M \bigotimes_R N, L)$, we define $\psi: \text{Hom}_R(M \bigotimes_R N, L) \to \text{Hom}_R(M,N; L)$ as $\psi(f) = f \circ \Phi$. We want $\psi$ to be an isomorphism, and then the remarks say this is equivalent to $\Phi$ being an initial object in $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$.

Comment: Paraphrasing the remark (again), I think what it says is that “if $\psi$ is an isomorphism, then $\Phi$ is an initial object in $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$”. I guess my confusion lies in not understanding the second part of that statement, i.e., what the following means: “given $g \in \mathscr{C}_{M,N}$, there exiss only one morphism $\Phi \to g$”.

Comment: just a small remark: usually we use \otimes for the tensor product as a binary operation, and reserve \bigotimes for the tensor product of a family of modules. In other words, \otimes is to $+$ as \bigotimes is to $\sum$.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the comma, reading it as times ($\times$). Although it seems odd notation to use for bilinear forms - it seems an abuse of the name Hom to me. @ensbana

Comment: What are you using $\Phi$ to mean? That seems like a definition of initial object. although I'd rephrase it: for an initial object in the category you need *exactly one* map. "Only one" is less precise.

Comment: $\Phi$ is a bilinear map $M \times N \to M \bigotimes_R N$. At the moment we actually don’t really know what $M \bigotimes_R N$ is, except that it is a $R$-module (with that associated map $\Phi$). My goal now is to show that, given $g \in \mathscr{C}_{M,N}$, there exists exactly one morphism $\Phi \to g$. But I don’t really understand what this condition mean and how to show it.

Comment: There’s also a discussion of morphisms in $\mathscr{C}_{M,N}$, but it’s not clear to me. It states that, given bilinear maps $g_1: M \times N \to L_1$ and $g_2: M \times N \to L_2$, there should exists a map $\tau: L_1 \to L_2$ such that $g_2 = \tau \circ g_1$. Can I interpret the morphism $g_1 \to g_2$ as this “relationship”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows, $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

Given two $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, **a tensor product of $M$ and $N$** is an $R$-module $M \otimes_R N$ together with a bilinear map $\otimes \colon M \times N \to M \otimes_R N$ *that has the following property*:

> For any $R$-module $L$, and any bilinear map $b \colon M \times N \to L$, there exists a unique linear map $l \colon M \otimes_R N \to L$ such that $l \circ \otimes = b$.

Observe that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, a function $f \colon X \to Y$ is bijective if and only if for any $y \in Y$ there exists a unique $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. With this in mind, observe that the above property is equivalent to the following:

> For any $R$-module $L$, the function
> $$\begin{align*}
> \operatorname{Hom}_R(M \otimes_R N,L) & \longrightarrow \operatorname{Bil}_R(M,N;L) \\ l & \longmapsto l \circ \otimes
> \end{align*}$$
> is bijective. (Indeed, it is an isomorphism of $R$-modules, but this doesn't matter here).

Finally, define the category $\mathscr B_{M,N}$ whose objects are bilinear maps $M \times N \to *$ (the codomain is any $R$-module), and for any two objects $b_1 \colon M \times N \to L_1$ and $b_2 \colon M \times N \to L_2$, a morphism $l \colon b_1 \to b_2$ is the same as a linear map $l \colon L_1 \to L_2$ such that $l \circ b_1 = b_2$. Thus, the defining property of the tensor product is also equivalent to the following:

> For any object $b$ of $\mathscr B_{M,N}$ there exists a unique morphism $l \colon \otimes \to b$. In other words, $\otimes$ is an initial object of $\mathscr B_{M,N}$.

Comment: Thanks. What tripped me up is the bit with “a morphism $l: b_1 \to b_2$ is the same as a linear map $l: L_1 \to L_2$…”. I read it in the text but wasn’t sure I could make that conclusion. Anyway, your notations are very clear and things make much more sense now.